# how to split a word file page wise using C#.NET(4) and open xml sdk 2.0?

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have my application written using C#.net and open XML SDK(2.0).I have spitted the word file paragraph wise and section wise using open XML tags.But i could not find anything about split a word file page wise...

Pleas Guide me get out of this issue.

Comment: I think there is no such tag. The document is not divided to pages, the flow of the document is split during rendering. It was true for doc format, and it's very possible for docx.

Comment: Agreed with LexRama - there is no such tag. Word documents are flow documents and technically do not have "pages".

Comment: thanks a lot.then what is the other options to get page wise splitting?

Comment: see Eric's answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

However, after Word (or Word Automation Services) has rendered the document, you can find the w:lastRenderedPageBreak element, which, combined with hard page breaks, can let you know where page breaks are.  There are no guarantees about this - you could potentially go into an Open XML document and alter content using the Open XML SDK, and then the w:lastRenderedPageBreak elements would not be in the correct place.

Comment: Wow, Eric White in the house! Welcome buddy!

Comment: Hi Eric, 
I want to know that How Can I find lastRenderedPageBreak element using ASP.Net VB/C# code?

My requirement is to read MS Word document page by page through OpenXML and then write those pages to PDF file.